# Tables in exchange server (.edb) file

Tags: exchange-server, esent, edb

Can anybody tell me what are the different tables used in an exchange server .edb file
and what are their schema.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [this tool](http://www.woany.co.uk/news/esedbviewer-v1-0-3/) that allows you to view the schema and its data.

Answer (score 1):

Joachim Metz has reverse engineered the edb file format. He also worked somewhat on the Exchange database. His project is open source and there's some documentation about the tables and columns of the exchange (and other) database.

Here's the link:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/libesedb/files/